# Varchar(255) to Varchar(MAX)

Tags: sql, types, varchar

Is it possible to change a column type in a SQL Server 2008 database from `varchar(255)` to `varchar(MAX)` without having to drop the table and recreate?

SQL Server Management Studio throws me an error every time I try to do it using that - but to save myself a headache would be nice to know if I can change the type without having to DROP and CREATE.

Thanks

Comment: Strange, tried it out in SQL Server 2005, works fine for me.

Comment: BTW, what was the error thrown?

Comment: 'Saving changes is not permitted. The changes you have made require the following tables to be dropped and re-created. You have either made changes to a table that can't be re-created or enabled the option Prevent saving changes that require table to be re-created.'

Option 'Prevent saving changes' is not enabled...

Comment: SQL Management Studio does that (see the change script for the SQL they use to alter the table), @astander's answer is a better alternative. Glad you found your solution :D

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You should be able to do it using TSQL.

Something like

```
ALTER TABLE [table] ALTER COLUMN [column] VARCHAR(MAX)
```

Answer (score 15):

> 'Saving changes is not permitted. The
>   changes you have made require the
>   following tables to be dropped and
>   re-created. You have either made
>   changes to a table that can't be
>   re-created or enabled the option
>   Prevent saving changes that require
>   table to be re-created.' Option
>   'Prevent saving changes' is not
>   enabled..

That's a new "feature" in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 which by default is turned on. Whenever you make a larger change, SSMS can only recreate the table by creating a new one and then moving over the data from the old one - all in the background (those changes include re-ordering of your columns amongst other things).

This option is turned off by default, since if your table has FK constraints and stuff, this way of re-doing the table might fail. But you can definitely turn that feature on!

[image]

It's under `Tools > Options` and once you uncheck that option you can do these kind of changes to table structure in the table designer again.

Comment: Thanks marc_s. I already had this un-ticked and it was still stopping me from making the changes. The alter statements by astander above worked when I wrote them themselves. Thanks :)

Comment: @JD: hmm... odd... usually that is the issue - glad you already have a solution, though!

Answer (score 3):

Be aware
with Something like

```
ALTER TABLE [table] ALTER COLUMN [column] VARCHAR(MAX)
```

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15007/change-length-of-varchar-on-live-prod-table

Martin Smith's answare:

If you are increasing it to `varchar(100 - 8000)` (i.e. anything other than `varchar(max))` and you are doing this through TSQL rather than the SSMS GUI

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourCol varchar(200) [NOT] NULL
```

and not altering column nullability from `NULL` to `NOT NULL` (which would lock the table while all rows are validated and potentially written to or from  `NOT NULL` to `NULL` in some circumstances then this is a quick metadata only change. It might need to wait for a `SCH-M` lock on the table but once it acquires that the change will be pretty much instant.

One caveat to be aware of is that during the wait for a `SCH-M` lock other queries will be blocked rather than jump the queue ahead of it so you might want to consider adding a `SET LOCK_TIMEOUT` first.

Also make sure in the `ALTER TABLE` statement you explicitly specify `NOT NULL` if that is the original column state as otherwise the column will be changed to allow `NULL`.

Comment: Isn't this identical to [this existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2696003/1402846)?

Comment: Why is it a problem to ALTER to varchar(MAX)?