# converting varchar(n) to varchar(max) on mssql2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, varcharmax

I have a table which has about 8,000 rows and I wanna change a column from varchar(1000) to varchar(max)
I typed

```
alter table TABLENAME alter column COLUMNNAME varchar(MAX)
```

and it didn't work.
How can I change the data type of the column?
Or do I have to write varchar(5000) or something instead of varchar(MAX)??
Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, Mike. But I turned off that option before I did that work. Also it is not related to any other tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following thread here on SO contains answer to your question. Take note that your table might get dropped and re-created during the process.

[convert to varchar(max)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2696343/1148611)